# produce a table/array with string column and numbers

Tags: string, matlab, cell

I have a cell structure of strings such as.

```
my_cell = 'apple.csv' 'banana.csv' 'orange.csv'
```

from reading in datasets

I have a vector of data.

```
my_number = [1 2 3]
```

I want to output a table/array that has the names in the first column and some numbers in the second.

```
my_output=['apple' 1; 'banana' 2; 'orange' 3]
```

Answer (score 0):

i think this will only work if your vector is the same size as your cell

```
my_output=cell(length(my_cell),2)

for i=1:length(my_cell)
my_output(i,:)=[my_cell(i),my_number(i)];
end
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to mix strings and numbers in the same array, your "table" needs to be a cell array:

```
my_cell = {'apple.csv','banana.csv','orange.csv'}; % data
my_number = [1 2 3]; % data

my_output = cell(length(my_cell),2); % initialize output cell array
[my_output{:,1}] = deal(my_cell{:}); % asign first column of cell array
my_number_cell = num2cell(my_number); % convert vector to cell
[my_output{:,2}] = deal(my_number_cell{:}); % asign first column of cell array
```

gives

```
>> disp(my_output)
    'apple.csv'     [1]
    'banana.csv'    [2]
    'orange.csv'    [3]
```

Answer (score 0):

Other than a cell array, you can also use [`dataset()`](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/stats/dataset.html), which after some initial overhead are lighter than than the former and also allow you to access its fields with `.` (dot) syntax, i.e. *'struct'* syntax:

```
% Example input
my_cell   = repmat({'apple.csv'; 'banana.csv'; 'orange.csv'} ,1000,1);
my_number = repmat([1; 2; 3],1000,1);

% a is a cell array, b is a dataset
a = [my_cell(:), num2cell(my_number(:))]
b = dataset({my_cell(:), 'name'},{my_number(:),'number'})
```

Displayed variables:

```
a = 
    'apple.csv'     [1]
    'banana.csv'    [2]
    'orange.csv'    [3]
b = 
    name                number
    'apple.csv'         1     
    'banana.csv'        2     
    'orange.csv'        3
```

Alternative ways to index a `dataset()`:

```
b(:,1)
ans = 
    name            
    'apple.csv'     
    'banana.csv'    
    'orange.csv'    

b.name
ans = 
    'apple.csv'
    'banana.csv'
    'orange.csv'

b(:,'number')
ans = 
    number
    1     
    2     
    3
```